# Creating Angular 2 component before the router does

Tags: angular2-routing

According to the documentation,

> When the browser's location URL changes to match the path segment /crisis-center, then the router activates an instance of the CrisisListComponent and displays its view.

Is there a way to " pre-activate " an instance of a component before navigating to the corresponding route, so that the router can then display its view immediately without having to create an instance itself?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, But you can [pre-fetch component data](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard), before Routing completes.

So when routing happens data can be fetched in the resolver, and component gets loaded only after that. you may write some event Hooks on router to display loader while routing is not complete.